# Divide a table so that it will increase to 2N instead of N^2?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

hello i am making a friend table but it is increasing squarely. Here is my table structure

```
id | friend_id | name  | category
1  | 2         | kashif| friend
2  | 1         | Hamid | colleagues
```

is there a solution to divide it into 2 and make it O(2N)

Comment: Is there a specific reason that your relationship is not symmetrical?
1-2 is friend and 2-1 is colleague?

Answer (score 4):

> [Can I] divide a table so that it will increase to 2N instead of N^2?

Not in this case, since there are O(n^2) possible relationships.

In the worst case, you will always have O(n^2) data.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to normalize. `name` should go into a `person` table with `id`. Do the same with `category`. Then your relationship/`friend` table will have `id | friend_id | category_id`. If they are all integer types, each row is 4 bytes x 3 columns or (8 bytes for the person `id`s if required, 1 byte for category type).

To answer your question:
You can't make it smaller if you want to have the relationships 2-way. But, if you don't mind slower queries, only maintain one side of the relationship and use `OR` in your SQL to select either by `id=x OR friend_id=x`.

```
id | friend_id | category_id
1  | 2         | 1
```

That means you lose the category information, or create a 2nd category_id column for what the `friend_id` considers the relationship type:

```
id | friend_id | person_category_id | friend_category_id
1  | 2         | 1                  | 2
```

And the `categories` table:

```
category_id | category_text
1           | friend
2           | colleague
```

(but that's bad design.)

Comment: Normalization has nothing to do with "id or not".  And that wasn't what was asked.  And the part that does address what was asked is plain wrong.  If you want to learn what useful replies to the question as asked look like, see Paul Draper's.

Comment: To answer what was asked, quoting myself: "`To answer your question: You can't make it smaller if you want to have the relationships 2-way.`" Following which, the method I've shown would reduce the size, even if at the cost of very bad design and performance impact. No harm and quite normal to point out obvious improvements (like `id`'s) regardless of what's been asked. Paul's answer is better/most accurate but mine isn't wrong. I've even pointed out that the suggestion is bad design. It's not as low as 2N but much lower than N^2; aka "an option".